# Does Mailgun provide an email server?

Tags: node.js, email, mailgun, nodemailer

I'm attempting to set up account confirmation and password resets passing through an intermediate email validation step first, but I'm still working through some of the details before implementation as I'm fairly new to back end development. My tech stack is Node, Express, mongoDB, Mongoose, Nodemailer, and potentially Mailgun (as it seems to be free for the purposes of my app).

As I have [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097074/6293170), sending emails from the web server where my app would be hosted on is generally a bad idea given that it has no reputation as an email server, and therefore likely to end up in a spam folder or rejected altogether.

Does Mailgun offer free email servers, or must I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can send up to 300 emails/day from your sandbox server to authorized recipients only.

On signup, Mailgun provides a sandbox server to test email delivery, however the sandbox server only allows emails to be sent to authorized recipients (i.e., recipients explicitly added to an authorized list in Mailgun). Of course, this will not do for anything production related.

In order to send emails to recipients without having them on an authorized list, one must provide their own domain.